# how to make it be shown only when the imposed condition of my when is met

Tags: python, ansible

I have the brief excerpt from an ansible playbook below, where it just checks for the existence of a directory on the server, when the playbook is not answered and closed, that is, if it does not exist, however I am facing difficulties to create the debug message , because even if it is answered as **true or false**, the message is shown, how to make it be shown only `when` the imposed condition of my when is met, in this case, **if the directory does not exist**.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:

  - name: Ansible check directory exists.
    stat:
      path: /opt/Zabbix/HC/
    register: result_dir

  - meta: end_play
    when: not result_dir.stat.exists
  - debug:
      msg: "Directory not exists"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to put it into a [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks). For example

```
    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: "Directory not exists. End of play."
        - meta: end_play
      when: not result.stat.exists

    - debug:
        msg: "Directory exists. Continue play."
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
      - name: Ansible check directory exists.
        stat:
             path: /opt/Zabbix/HC/
        register: result_dir

      - debug:
             msg: "Directory not exists"
        when: result_dir.stat.exists == false

      - meta: end_play
        when: result_dir.stat.exists == false
```

this will help you.

Comment: you can remove the debug statment if you want.